# Typescript how to create interface with spefic keys from other

Tags: typescript

i have an interface User `{ id: number, name: string, adress: string}`
So i wont to have an interface with all keys from User, but other types, like `{id: string, name: SomeName, SomeAdress}`.
How to solve it?

Comment: If the properties in the new type all have the same value type it's as simple as `type ObjectifiedUser = Record<keyof User, SomeObject>;`

Comment: @AluanHaddad thx. but they are different

Comment: Is there some kind of pattern that you follow, given the names of the properties or are the different value types arbitrary? I feel like you need to elaborate your question because the answer is going to be radically different depending on that, and also whether or not you plan to do this to multiple types as a generic operation

Comment: There are also many ways of doing this, given a property name, it could be matched to a specific value type in the new type. Or, given a value type based on both the name and the type of the source property